# using coalescing null operator on nullable types changes implicit type

Tags: c#, resharper, implicit, null-coalescing-operator

I would expect the next three lines of code to be the same:

```
public static void TestVarCoalescing(DateTime? nullableDateTime)
{
  var dateTimeNullable1 = nullableDateTime.HasValue ? nullableDateTime : DateTime.Now;
  var dateTimeNullable2 = nullableDateTime != null ? nullableDateTime : DateTime.Now;
  var dateTimeWhatType = nullableDateTime ?? DateTime.Now;
}
```

In all cases, I assign `nullableDateTime` to the new variable. I would expect the type of all variables to become `DateTime?` since that is the type of `nullableDateTime`. But to my surprise, the type of `dateTimeWhatType` just becomes `DateTime`, so not nullable.

To make things worse, ReSharper suggests to replace the second statement with a null coalescing expression, turning it into expression 3. So if I let ReSharper do its thing, the type of the variable will change from `DateTime?` to `DateTime`.

In fact, let's say that in the remainder of the method, I would use

```
if (someCondition) dateTimeNullable2 = null;
```

That would compile just fine, until I let ReSharper replace the second expression with the null coalescing version.

AFAIK, replacing

```
somevar != null ? somevar : somedefault;
```

with

```
somevar ?? somedefault;
```

should indeed produce the same result. But for implicit typing on a nullable type, the compiler seems to threat `??` as if it means.

```
somevar != null ? somevar.Value : somedefault;
```

So I guess my question is why the implicit type is changed when I use `??`, and also where in the documentation I could find info on this.

*BTW, this isn't a real world scenario, but I would like to know why using `??` changes the (implicit) type.*

Comment: Why would you expect `nullableDateTime ?? DateTime.Now` to produce a `DateTime?`, when the compiler has sufficient information to know that the result will never be `null`?

Comment: @Damien: in my first and second example the compiler also has sufficient information to know the result will never be `null`. That's exactly the reason why I find this behavior kind of odd.

Comment: But `?:` support a much larger range of possible inputs (there's no reason the `condition` need be connected to either result `expression` at all). As such, it would be unusual for the compiler to be architected to perform this analysis against `?:`. Whereas, for `??`, it knows exactly that the result will be the first expression with no possibility of that expression being null, or the second expression.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your first two examples are leading you astray; better would be to consider not your

```
var dateTimeNullable1 = nullableDateTime.HasValue 
    ? nullableDateTime 
    : DateTime.Now;
```

but rather

```
var dateTimeNullable1 = nullableDateTime.HasValue 
    ? nullableDateTime.Value 
    : DateTime.Now;
```

---

To quote section 7.12 "The null coalescing operator" of the C# 3.0 spec (apologies for slightly ropey formatting):

> The type of the expression `a ?? b` depends on which implicit
>   conversions are available between the types of the operands. In order
>   of preference, the type of `a ?? b` is `A`<sub>`0`</sub>, `A`, or `B`,
>   where `A` is the type of `a`, `B` is the type of `b` (provided that
>   `b` has a type), and `A`<sub>`0`</sub> is the underlying type of `A` if
>   `A` is a nullable type, or `A` otherwise.

So if `a` is `Nullable<Something>`, and `b` can be implicitly converted to `Something`, the type of the whole expression will be `Something`. As @Damien_The_Unbeliever suggests, the *point* of this operator is to coalesce nulls!

Comment: So far I had only searched the [MSDN documentation on `??`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) and [Using Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx). They never use `var` in those examples but assign to an explicit type. Anyway, apparently `a ?? b` is **not** exactly the same as `a != null ? a : b` when it comes to nullable types.

Answer (score 5):

To go all language lawyer, for a moment. From the C# spec (version 4):

> **7.13**
>
> The type of the expression `a ?? b` depends on which implicit conversions are available on the operands. In order of preference, the type of `a ?? b` is `A0`, `A`, or `B`, where `A` is the type of `a` (provided that `a` has a type), `B` is the type of `b` (provided that `b` has a type), and `A0` is the underlying type of `A` if `A` is a nullable type, or `A` otherwise.

So, `??` is explicitly defined to prefer the underlying type of the first expression, if that first expression is a nullable type.

Whereas the language from **7.14** (dealing with `?:`) only discusses the actual types of `x` and `y`, from the form `b ? x : y`, and discusses *implicit* conversions between these two types.

> If an implicit conversion (§6.1) exists from X to Y, but not from Y to X, then Y is the type of the conditional expression

Since [`Nullable(T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) defines an *implicit* conversion from `T` to `Nullable(T)`, and only an *explicit* conversion from `Nullable(T)` to `T`, the only possible type of the overall expression is `Nullable(T)`.