# How differs the implementation of null operators in C# including "??" and "?."?

Tags: c#

Recently I have encountered "??" and "?." operators in C#.
I wonder if someone could tell me how these two operators work and what are their main use cases and possible differences?
Any guide or help appreciated in advance.

Comment: '??' is called the "null coalescing operator". There are a lot of posts about it here on SO.  I recommend just entering it into the search bar.  There is a good post for it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11960732/understanding-the-null-coalescing-operator

Answer (score 2):

`??` [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)

`?.` and `?[]` [null-conditional operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators)